# SQL query for getting the most used items from a SET column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

We have a table of user profiles in a mysql database, and one of the fields is a `SET` column which tracks the user's groups.

the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_profiles` (
  `userId` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `groups` set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20')
 );
```

I want to get the most popular groups in a sorted descending list, however the fact that we used a `SET` column makes it a little difficult using functions such as `COUNT`.

I can get a specific group count by running this query:

```
SELECT count(NULLIF(`interests` & 1,0)) as Count1stVal FROM users_profiles;
```

however, i don't want to run a query for each group and then calculating the most popular groups

Comment: Why does it make difficult? It should be no difference. Probably you should add what you tried so far, so it's more clear where you're hitting the road block.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT comes to mind. Probably that's what you're looking for, together with GROUP BY. Or just GROUP BY and COUNT(groups).

Comment: Should one take from your question that it is not possible to normalise the data structure?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion, but not actual code (since I am not that familiar with the set data type).

First, create a temporary table or subquery that has one row for each element of the set.  Each row would have exactly that element in its set.  Call this Elements.

Second, do the following query:

```
select e.element, count(*)
from user_profiles up join
     Elements e
     on up.groups like concat('%', e.element, '%')
group by e.element
order by 2 desc
```

Now, the only problem is that your set values overlap with each other.  So, you have "1" and "10", so this will not quite work.  You can do one of the following to fix this.

1. Rename the set values (your actual table may not have this problem, for instance).
2. Use the "&" operation and a generated list of numbers.  In this case, the on statement changes to:

   on up.groups & e.element > 0

The page http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/mysql/the-mysql-set-datatype gives a good overview of what you can do with sets.  It also explains why they are often discouraged . . . since they do not provide the functionality of a normalized table.

Comment: thanks for the link. it was helpful as little, but I'm still looking for a solution for it. the numeric values are an issue, so using string `CONCAT` won't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    groups, # get the group number
    COUNT(groups) AS group_cnt # use this for sorting
FROM users_profiles
GROUP BY groups
ORDER BY group_cnt DESC
```

I do not have a server on this machine, so I can not test it, but I think it should work as expected.

EDIT: the query only works when there is only one value in the groups column.

If you were to have a different table where the groups would be listed as entries with the id corresponding to the number in the set, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    g.id, # the group id corresponds to the groups in the set
    COUNT(up.userId) as g_cnt # count the number of users with the group
FROM (
    users_profiles up,
    groups g
)
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(g.id, up.groups) > 0
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g_cnt DESC
```

But if you are introducing a groups table, then it would maybe be best to normalize this into a many-to-many relation between users and groups

Comment: i tried that, but it counts groups based on the value of the column, which is made out of a number of groups (meaning that it's actually count different sets of groups)

Comment: What do you mean by "counts groups based on the value of the column", because I've just tested this and it works. It gives me the group numbers and their count ordered from the most common to the rarest group.

Comment: your solution would probably work if the column were an `ENUM`. when i ran the query, I'm getting results of mixed groups, such as "1,2,20" and it's count

Comment: Yes the set can have multiple values and that would render my first query unusable, that is something I did not know. Anyway I've edited the reply to write what I would do in a situation like that, since it was a bit much for a comment